# How to subclass from QStandardItem?

Tags: c++, qt

I am getting unexpected errors when deriving from `QStandardItem`. How I added my derive class is Add New >> C++ Class. Choose base class as `QObject` and once the class is created I renamed `QObject`with `QStandardItem`.

```
#include <QStandardItem>

class XmlItem : public QStandardItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    //explicit XmlItem(QObject *parent = 0);
    explicit XmlItem(QStandardItem *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
};

XmlItem::XmlItem(QStandardItem *parent) : QStandardItem()
{

}
```

This gives the following errors (there are more of these)

```
\debug\moc_XmliIem.cpp:64: error: C2039: 'staticMetaObject' : is not a member of 'QStandardItem'
\debug\moc_XmliIem.cpp:71: error: C2227: left of '->metaObject' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
\debug\moc_XmliIem.cpp:71: error: C2227: left of '->dynamicMetaObject' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

If I comment out `Q_OBJECT` the errors strangely goes away but obviously I need it because I will have signals and slots.

Why am I getting these errors and how to derive properly from `QStandardItem`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QStandardItem` does not inherit from `QObject`

To be able to use signal/slots in `XmlItem`, you'd need to inherit from QObject yourself, i.e.:

```
class XmlItem : public QObject, public QStandardItem 
{
     Q_OBJECT

     //...
};
```

Comment: Wow I didn't realise that, i assumed everything gets derived from `QObject` in Qt.

Comment: the big question is: 'why do you need a model item that can emit signals when the model itself emits signals when an item changes?'. it could also reduce your applications performance when you have a big model with lots of these items